# How to trim whitespaces from JSON output in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express

On Node.js using Express, I am outputting JSON with a simple `response.send(myObject)` It's working fine, but the response has a lot of white spaces indentations. Removing them reduces the size by half. Is there a quick/proper way to do this? I tried using `JSON.stringify` and it works great, but that turns the response type to `text/html`

Comment: Check the express settings its one of the settings (json spaces off the top of my head). It's automatically 0 on production mode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a config setting was introduced in 3.0.0alpha1

try app.set('json spaces',0)

Comment: Awesome! Looks like Express will actually automatically remove the white spaces in production env. [More info here.](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app-settings) So no changes needed.

Comment: Wow I added this to my app and it made js-yaml's output nice and spaceless!

Answer (score 1):

you can also compress your output which will remove uncessary whitespaces by gzipping it.

```
  app.use(express.compress());
```